# Restrictions on crossing edges in Delaunay triangulations

Tags: graph-theory, computational-geometry, triangulations

what can be said about crossing edges in Delaunay triangulations, i.e. about pairs of edges that constitute to the heaviest perfect matching int the $K_4$ induced by the quadruplet of adjacent vertices:

- does their existence imply that all edges of their induced $K_4$ are also edges of the DT?
- what is the maximal number of pairs of crossing edges a given edge can belong to?

Comment: Could you please explain what is a crossing edge in a DelTri? I don't understand the definition in terms of "the heaviest perfect matching in ... $K_4$ ..." Are the endpoints of crossing edges cocircular?

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke if the four vertices are in convex configuuration then the two diagonals have maximal weightsum and thus resemble the pair of crossing edges; if they are however in deltoid configuration then the pair of edges with maximal weightsum doesn't geometrically intersect but, by definition, are crossing.
If a DT would contain a pair of crossing edges that are adjacent to vertices $(A,C)$ and $(B,D)$ but e.g. edges $(A,B),\,(C,D)$ were not in the DT, replacing edges $(A,C),\,(B,D)$ with $(A,B),\,(C,D)$ would reduce the overall sum of edgelengths in the resultig graph

Comment: Thanks for trying, but I think we must not share common assumptions and language on this topic. I'm going to let this go ....

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke my apologies for my inability to provide a better explanation; maybe I will manage that in some future edit. I appreciate your honest feedback.